# How to check domain details in Python3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dns

I want to check the validity of a domain name (say, google.com) and also other details like domain age, expiry date, registrant country etc. Some of these problems are solved by Who-is but their paid solution is too expensive for me to use.

Does anybody have any clue how this can be done in Python3?

Comment: [This](https://github.com/richardpenman/pywhois) should help.

Comment: Simply search for whois on PYPI. There are lots of packages, which might help.

Comment: @OlvinRoght: thanks, that library was exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Use the new RDAP protocol that is available for any gTLD since this August, and it will be **far** simpler that using whois, so skip this legacy old protocol.

You can go to https://www.icann.org/rdap for a lot of explanations.

Since you mention a `.COM`, you can find registry RDAP server by going to https://data.iana.org/rdap/dns.json and you will find it is https://rdap.verisign.com/com/v1/

Once you are used to RDAP you then know that you need to do this query:
https://rdap.verisign.com/com/v1/domain/google.com

If all goes well you will get back a JSON content, with all the data you need.

Note however that:

- `.COM/.NET` is a thin registry: today (this will change) it does not have any data whatsoever about contacts, including the registrant. But `.COM/.NET` regitrars are now mandated to have an RDAP server also so once you know who is the registrar of any domain (and you have a link to its RDAP server in the registry RDAP server reply) you can query its own RDAP server for further details
- for all gTLDs, and due to GDPR, they are under some ICANN temporary specification that basically has the consequence that no contact data will be displayed (either in whois or RDAP in fact) only typically a link or an obfuscated email to join the registrant, and like only the country.

Some examples:

```
$ wget -qO - https://rdap.verisign.com/com/v1/domain/google.com | jq '.events[] | select(.eventAction | contains("expiration")) | .eventDate'
"2028-09-14T04:00:00Z"

$ wget -qO - https://rdap.markmonitor.com/rdap/domain/GOOGLE.COM | jq '.entities[] | select(.roles[0] | contains("registrant")) | .vcardArray[1] | .[2][3][6]'
"US"
```

(Note that registrar RDAP server does not conform to current ICANN specification because last element of address should be country full name and country ISO code should be in a separate "CC" property).

Of course a proper RDAP client or library will shield you from such details and provide easy accessors to data.

PS: and even if you do not use RDAP but insist on whois, DO NOT use whois blindly towards any server, use only the authoritative sources, that is the registries.